# Search for an identifier containing three names

Tags: sql, hive

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Stat |
| 10 | FCSM |
| 10 | EGRUL |
| 9 | FCSM |
| 9 | EGRUL |
| 8 | FCSM |

Result

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Stat |
| 10 | FCSM |
| 10 | EGRUL |

Good afternoon.
Tell me how to find all an identifier that has only three names (Stat,EGRUL,FCSM). Those identifiers that have only two or one name should not be included in the result.

```
select * from table 
where (name ='Stat') and (name='EGRUL') and (name='FCSM)
order by id
```

Why is this query not working?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please share us what you have tried so far, what problems you encountered with those solutions and exactly what is not working. Please read more about [ask] in [help]. To do some research on your own in general, please take a look at the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses in standard SQL or in the RDBMS' documentation.

Comment: Your query tried to filter rows with 'name' column equals to three values at once. If your group you query by 'id' and check rows count in having clause as @Pred suggested, you will get what you need. Try something like `SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from table 
group by id
having string_agg(name, ',' order by name) = 'EGRUL,FCSM,Stat'
order by id
```